# Conflicts between frame.width and constraints (I think)

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage

I am making a form of progress bar so you can see how many rounds through a game the user is. I have been running into issues with UIImages that I have resized using:

```
self.progBar.frame.size.width = 50 (for example)
```

When I change the image in an adjacent UIImage element then the progBar width changes at the same time. After hours of searching I have come to the conclusion that it is resetting back to the original constraint value. I then made an IBOutlet and changed the constant to what the width should be at that time but it still resets back to the original constraint width.

I know I have not included any specific code but thats because I'm more curious about if I am approaching this all wrong and frame.size is the incorrect way to go? I have removed the progress bar completely for know but I would like to learn for the next time.

Any discussion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are correct that mixing *frames* and *constraints* can cause conflicts, but it sounds like you are taking the right direction. Based on your post, you have set auto-layout constraints in IB/Storyboard, you've assigned a `Width` constraint to an IBOutlet, and then in code you set the `.constant` of that constraint? If so, but your view is still "resetting", then it sounds like you now have conflicting constraints... Do you get any error / warning output in the debug console when you try that?

Comment: I recreated it but there were no errors. I'm glad I was on the right path though, maybe I understand more than I realised! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the constraints override the frame changing...
just use this before changing the frame

```
someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

read here from apple docs [translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco)

Comment: Perfect - this worked! After hours of googling this never came up once, you guys are brilliant! Any idea why this works, or what it really does? I presume it just makes the constraints match the changes we have made to the frame? From that I also presume that frames are in fact masks as well? Blown my mind...

Comment: Doh! Why didn't I just look that up. Thanks for the follow up